# JSON decode specific field golang

Tags: json, go

I have this simple function, which gets a JSON response from a specific URI. The function accepts the `httpRequest` and an `interface{}`, which is a pointer to the struct in which I want to unmarshal my JSON response.

```
func (c *Client) SendRequest(req *http.Request, v interface{}) error {
      ...
      
      return json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&v)
}
```

An example of JSON response is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "9da7a204-544e-5fd1-9a12-61176c5d4cd8"
  }
}
```

An example of struct is:

```
type User struct {
        ID  string `json:"id;omitempty"`
    }
```

Now, the problem is the `data` object. With this object, the Decode operation fails, as the object it is not included in my struct. I would like to Decode the content of `data` object directly, without using a temporary struct, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: The JSON is not a "simple" object, but an object with a `"data"` field whose value is another JSON object. You must use a struct with a field whose type is another struct.

Answer (score 2):

Use a struct that contains a `User` struct to unmarshal into. See Response struct below.

```
type User struct {
    ID string `json:"id;omitempty"`
}

type Response struct {
    Data User `json:"data"`
}
```

After unmarshaling if `r` is your `Response` instance you can access your `User` by `r.Data`

Since you don't know the type at compile time you can use `interface{}` as the type of the field too.

```
type Response struct {
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}

r := Response{
    Data: &User{},
}

json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&r)
```

And then get your user instance by

```
userNew, _ := r.Data.(*User)
```

P.S: You have a typo on your code at json tag. Replace `;` by `,`